# What's the difference between \chaptername and \chapapp in KOMA-Script?

Tags: sectioning, chapters, koma-script

It seems that these two commands do exactly the same thing... - So where's the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In KOMA `\chapapp` is just `\@chapapp`, which is a macro that is normally (and probably also in KOMA) `\chaptername` unless you are in an appendix, in which case it is `\appendixname`.

This way `\chapter` can easily have two different names without having to duplicate code.